# For Looping in C#?

Tags: c#, for-loop, conditional-statements

This is my program:

```
Console.WriteLine(" A " + " B " + " C ");
        for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 2; y <= 20; y += 2)
            {
                for (int z = 1; z <= 20; z += 2)
                {
                    if (z % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(x+" " + y +" " + z);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

Now the problem here is it's not showing what I want it to look like but instead it keeps on repeating.
I want it to look like this where B contains only even numbers and C contains only odd numbers.

```
A  B  C
1  2  1
2  4  3
3  6  5
4  8  7
5  10 9
6  12 11
7  14 13
8  16 15
9  18 17
10 20 19
```

And the how do I add and multiply the given? I need to multiply A and B and add it to C
The output should look like:

```
3
11
23
39
59
83
111
143
179
219
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
    Console.WriteLine(" A " + " B " + " C ");
    for(int x=1,y=2,z=1;x<=10;x++,y+=2,z+=2)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(x+" " + y +" " + z);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(" Sum ");
    for(int x=1,y=2,z=1;x<=10;x++,y+=2,z+=2)
    {
         Console.WriteLine((x*y+z).ToString());
    }
```

To get your give formate

```
Console.WriteLine(" A " + " B " + " C ");
for(int x=1,y=2,z=1;x<=10;x++,y+=2,z+=2)
{

     Console.Write(" "+x);
     if(x<10)
     Console.Write("  "+y);
     else
     Console.Write(" "+y);

     if(y<10)
      Console.Write("  "+z);
     else
      Console.Write(" "+z);
      Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 A  B  C 
 1  2  1
 2  4  3
 3  6  5
 4  8  7
 5  10 9
 6  12 11
 7  14 13
 8  16 15
 9  18 17
 10 20 19
```

Comment: It works thank you! Do you know the way on how to put the output as I said so in the post?

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
Console.WriteLine(" A " + " B " + " C ");
int y = 0;
int z= 1;

for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
{
    Console.Write(x +" ");
    y+=2;
    Console.Write(y +" ");


    if (z % 2 != 0)
    {
        Console.Write(z);
        z += 2;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```